# CSS Frameworks like 960 and Blueprint?

Tags: css, 960.gs, blueprint-css, css-frameworks, yaml-css

*This is at the framework level, not dealing directly with CSS, so posting to SO.*

I just learned about the existence of CSS frameworks. 960 Grid System seems pretty awesome, then I found Blueprint, which seems to do the same thing and more.

**Is there a better word than "framework" to categorize this?**

**Are there any other products in this category?**
In response to one of the comments [[Link to a site designed using a CSS framework (Blueprint, 960,etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483565/link-to-a-site-designed-using-a-css-framework-blueprint-960-etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483565/link-to-a-site-designed-using-a-css-framework-blueprint-960-etc), "how many example frameworks do you want?  he just listed two of them.", I'd love to have more than two examples, unless those are the only two in the running.

- [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/),
  which is "the original CSS framework"
- [960 Grid
  System](http://960.gs/), which is a tool to have a
  grid underlying your screen.
- [YUI
  2: Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/), similar to 960?  The rest of YUI is more similar to JQuery?
- [YAML: Yet Another Multicolumn Layout](http://www.yaml.de/en/), is what it says on the tin.  Has the most SO results.
- [Elements](http://elements.projectdesigns.org/), which also focuses somewhat on your work process.
- [Tripoli](http://devkick.com/lab/tripoli/).
- [A CSS Framework](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/a-css-framework).

Comment: Please note that some/most of the posted frameworks are outdated by now. An up to date list of similar frameworks can be found here: https://github.com/troxler/awesome-css-frameworks

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few more for your list

http://elements.projectdesigns.org/

http://devkick.com/lab/tripoli/

http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/a-css-framework

Comment: I have experimented with them and use bits and pieces like Elements external links plugin.  Of those three, I am most intrigued by tripoli which has a more straight forward language for the styles, #primary, #secondary, etc.. and sets an excellent base for typography and forms. However, blueprint is the one I am stuck on mainly for the reason that I have that framework memorized and is the quickest for me to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Elastic CSS Framework](http://elasticss.com/). Its main feature is that you are *not* enforced to have exactly N columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "framework" is okay to use here because it denotes a collection of useful, reusable components that abstract away the repetitious and error-prone aspects of a project and allow you, the developer, to focus on the task at hand.

Traditionally a framework is an programming API (which these CSS frameworks are not) so you could be pedantic and say that these CSS foundations are not frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like "framework" in this case is more like a "scaffold" used in construction, and less like an actual programming MVC setup.

Comment: Well, "framework" doesn't always mean "MVC".  :-)  JQuery is certainly a framework and API on which other JQuery packages are built; it has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

There are also:
[The Golden Grid](http://code.google.com/p/the-golden-grid/)

[Emastic - CSS Framework](http://code.google.com/p/emastic/)

[Malo - CSS Framework](http://code.google.com/p/malo/)

Answer (score 0):

Fluid Grid System - http://fluid.newgoldleaf.com/

Main benefit is that it can contain nested containers.